# ExecuteNonQuery() returns -1 when execute the stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute stored procedure in Visual Studio. Its given below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addStudent] 
    @stuName varchar(50), 
    @address varchar(100),
    @tel varchar(15),
    @etel varchar(15),
    @nic varchar (10),
    @dob date


AS 
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @currentID INT
    DECLARE @existPerson INT
    SET @existPerson = (SELECT p_ID FROM Student WHERE s_NIC = @nic);
    IF @existPerson = null
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Person (p_Name, p_RegDate, p_Address, p_Tel, p_EmergeNo, p_Valid, p_Userlevel)
            VALUES (@stuName,  GETDATE(), @address, @tel, @etel, 0, 'Student' );
            SET @currentID = (SELECT MAX( p_ID) FROM Person); 
            INSERT INTO Student (p_ID, s_Barcode, s_DOB, s_NIC) VALUES (@currentID , NULL, @dob, @nic);
            return 0;
        END
    ELSE
        return -1;
END
```

Im doing so by using this code below.

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        Connect conn = new Connect();
        con = conn.getConnected();
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("addStudent", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@stuName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nameTxt.Text.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = addressTxt.Text.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@tel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = telTxt.Text.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@etel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emerTxt.Text.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@nic", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nicTxt.Text.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dobTime.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");

                    int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show(n.ToString());
```

But it returns me -1. I tried this stored procedure by entering the same values I captured from debugging. It was successful. What can be the possible error?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: try making `@dob` as Datetime instead of Date . Because in C# code @dob is SqlDbType.Datetime. change accordingly and see if it helps?

Comment: Instead of using the `SET @currentID = (SELECT MAX)` line, try using `@@IDENTITY`. Not related to the error, but just a tip.

Comment: You should really use `yyyyMMdd` format for dates and not `MM-dd-yyyy` or similar formats, it's much more culture agnostic that way.

Comment: @Seph - they ought to be passing them as `DateTime`s and not formatting them into strings at all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use `= null`, use `is null`

```
IF @existPerson is null
```

When you compare anything `= null` the result is always false (unless you have `set ansi_nulls off`, which you shouldn't, as such an option is deprecated)

Even better, you can use

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT p_ID FROM Student WHERE s_NIC = @nic)
```

Also, you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `SET @currentID = (SELECT MAX( p_ID) FROM Person);`

```
SET @currentID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Finally you also need to add a parameter to collect the return value

```
   SqlParameter retValue = cmd.Parameters.Add("return", SqlDbType.Int);
   retValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

then

```
MessageBox.Show(retValue.Value);
```

Answer (score 12):

Let's have a look at the *documentation* for [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. ... *For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.*

You're calling a stored procedure, which, in and of itself, is none of the 3 listed statements where a row count is returned.

---

If you want to determine the value that was passed to a `return` statement within the stored procedure, you need to add another parameter to the command, and set its [`Direction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.direction.aspx) property to [`ReturnValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection.aspx) (the name you give to this parameter will be ignored)

Comment: This is wrong, if the stored procedure is doing an Update, Insert or Delete it will return the number of rows affected by this command if it is called by ExecuteNonQuery. A stored procedure in this case is not considered a statement, statements inside the stored procedure are.

Comment: SO won't let me remove my upvote so I'm commenting - this answer is wrong. The reason I thought it was correct was because I had "SET NOCOUNT ON" within my stored procedure. But when I used "SET NOCOUNT OFF" as @Ahitosh's answer says then `ExecuteNonQuery()` correctly returns the number of affected rows updated within my stored procedure.

Comment: Right answer. But don't have to be mean about it. I can see how it could be confusing. Let's say I have a stored procedure which performs one of those operations and nothing else? I can easily see how that could be mistaken as a "bug".

Answer (score 10):

To resolve this problem just remove "SET NOCOUNT ON" or Change it to "SET NOCOUNT OFF". and everything works fine!

Comment: It helped me as well as:
1) SET NOCOUNT ON is indicating that number of rows effect by T-SQL will not be returned
2) SET NOCOUNT OFF mean that number of rows effect by T-SQL will be returned.