# Data is inserted into database but shows the error message

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am new to c# and having issue inserting data form form to database. The following are the codes of classes and procedure definitions. While I press the button `Save(btnSaveUser)` it shows the error message

> Some errors occurred while processing the request

while the data is inserted in database whether it shows the error message.

`btnSaveUser` code:

```
private void btnSaveUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int result = uc.ManageUser(txtFullName.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtEmail.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerJoinedDate.Text), txtUserame.Text, txtPassword.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerCreatedDate.Text), "I");

        if (result == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("New User Saved");
            dgvUserDetails.DataSource = uc.SelectAllUsers();
            //MakeFieldsBlank();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SOME ERRORS OCCURRED WHILE PROCESSING THE REQUEST");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

`UserClass.cs`:

```
public class UserClass
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DataConnectionClass.DbConnection);

    public int ManageUser(String Name, String Address, String Phone, String Email, DateTime JoinedDate, String Username, String Password,DateTime CreatedDate,String Mode)
    {
        try
        {
            int result = 0;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ManageUser", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffID",DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JoinedDate", JoinedDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", CreatedDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mode", Mode);

            conn.Open();
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Procedure definition:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ManageUser]
    @StaffID int,
    @Name nvarchar(100),
    @Address nvarchar(500),
    @Phone nvarchar(100),
    @Email nvarchar(100),
    @JoinedDate date,
    @Username nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(max),
    @CreatedDate date,
    @Mode varchar(1)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if(@Mode='I')
        insert into tbl_Staff     (Name, Address, Phone, Email, JoinedDate, Username, Password, CreatedDate) 
        values(@Name, @Address, @Phone, @Email, @JoinedDate, @Username, @Password, @CreatedDate)

    if(@Mode='U')
       Update tbl_Staff 
       set Name = @Name,
           Address = @Address,
           Phone = @Phone,
           Email = @Email,
           JoinedDate = @JoinedDate,
           Username = @Username,
           Password = @Password,
           CreatedDate = @CreatedDate 
       where 
           StaffID = @StaffID

    if(@Mode='D')
        Delete from tbl_Staff 
        where StaffID = @StaffID
end
```

Comment: you do thats *your* error message you are seeing?

Comment: Side note: Do not throw in that way. You loose the stack trace. Just throw without exception. But if you don't have anything to do in that catch then remove it

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1):

`UserClass.ManageUser()` returns the result of [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns the number of rows affected.  Looking at the stored procedure, it executes [`SET NOCOUNT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837(v=sql.100).aspx), which stops the number of rows affected by the stored procedure from being returned.  That explains why you see the message.

Try commenting out `SET NOCOUNT ON` and that should allow the number of rows inserted to be returned.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As you suggested i used SET NOCOUNT OFF; which allowed the insertion of data.

Answer (score 0):

This:

[ExecuteNonQuery() returns -1 when execute the stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932471/c-executenonquery-returns-1-when-execute-the-stored-procedure)

says the return value is always -1 for stored procedures.

Have you checked what it is actually returning? If it's always returning -1 then you will always get an error message.

Comment: Not true. Read also the comment in the mentioned answer. It is the NOCOUT ON that drives the return value to -1

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I checked your link and was really helpful. As suggested on the link I changes SET NOCOUNT ON to SET NOCOUNT OFF. Which solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks I learnt something today. @Crshan, be aware that if your SP affects more than one record it will also throw the error message.